# ItemTouchHepler и RecyclerView - как получить время "задвижения" элемета

Tags: android, android-sdk, material-design, android-animation, swipe

Я использую [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html) для реализации свайпов для элементов списка RecyclerView. Вот так это выглядит на деле (*анимации замедленны в 10 раз*):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На гифке выше я медленно делаю свайп, почти доводя точку касания до левого края экрана, а потом отпускаю палец и элемент сам "задвигается" к левому краю. После это появляется ТОТ ЖЕ ЭЛЕМЕНТ, но с красым backgroud'ом и теперь все его View скрыты (GONE), а кнопка Undo становится видимой (VISIBLE). Вопрос - как мне узнать, сколько времени будет "задвигаться" элемент назад, т.е. как долго кнопка Undo будет двигаться от левого края к правому?

**Зачем мне это нужно**:
Вы могли заметить, что красный фон не изменяет себя по высоте, когда нижний элемент начинает двигать вверх, заполняя образовавшуюся пустоту. Я хочу заанимировать красный фон, чтобы он постепенно менял свою высоту, вместе с движение нижнего элемента. Чтобы это сделать, мне нужно знать сколько времени будет "выдвигаться" кнопка Undo.

Кроме того, может я вообще все делаю неправильно с точки зрения дизайна и элементы с отступами вообще не должны иметь функцию свайпа? Пожалуйста, подскажите мне как лучше реализовать дизайн для корзины покупок?

Корзина реализована фрагментом [ShoppingCartFragment.java](https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/blob/swipe_animation_StackOverflow/app/src/main/java/com/webtrust/tennosushi/fragments/ShoppingCartFragment.java), а адаптер для `RecyclerView`, который используется в этом фрагменте, реализован в [ShoppingCartItemRecyclerViewAdapter.java](https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/blob/swipe_animation_StackOverflow/app/src/main/java/com/webtrust/tennosushi/adapters/ShoppingCartItemRecyclerViewAdapter.java). Извиняюсь, что код выкладываю не сюда, а на гитхаб - это из-за ограничения на 30000 символов. Я поместил весь свой проект в [отдельную ветку](https://github.com/RareScrap/TennoSushi/tree/swipe_animation_StackOverflow) для StackOverflow, чтобы этот код в будущем не пропал.

Comment: В google keep есть отступы

Comment: А в яндекс почте кнопка отменить появляются снизу поверх экрана